# Should I created a different table to hold a big text / varchar field in MySQL 5.5.61 with Antelope file format?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, varchar, antelope

I read that newer version of MySQL save the big text fields apart from the rest of the row, so we don't have to bother about it.

However, how about an older version, specifically MySQL 5.5? Is it good for speed and performance purposes to save my text field in a different table?

Comment: if you want good performance, sometimes you just need to update.

Comment: InnoDB has always had off-record storage for big `TEXTs`/`BLOBs`.  Starting with 5.6, some of the details have changed and more options for `ROW_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 1):

The non-inline version of text storage a slower access because its in a different page in the tablespace, however in a separate table it has to access the PK of a separate table, and then take the slower access to access the text column in a different page.

So a separate table is worse for performance.